# Copy record to another table adding fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

`tab1` (`field1, field2, field3`)
`tab2` (`field1, field2,field3, field4`)

I want to copy a record from `tab1` to `tab2` taking all the fields **and** adding a value for `field4`.

How can I select `field1`, `field2` and `field3` from `tab2` and also add a value? I know that `SELECT` and `VALUES` in a `INSERT` query are mutually exclusive.

Thanks in advance.
Gustavo.

Comment: How is the value for field4 determined?  Is it a constant, is it a function of the other values, is it from some other table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know Oracle, but in Ms SQL it works like this:

```
insert into tab2 (field1, field2, field3, field4) 
select field1, field2, field3, 'New Value' from tab1
```

Comment: Yes, this would work in Oracle.  Of course this example assumes the value for field4 is a constant.